# how to split the numbers in android .split();

Tags: android, split

i have problem with splitting text/numbers method, i want to split the numbers of the Text Edit line and i have this code does i'm doing the wrong way ?
Here is my whole code:

```
    package com.trafika.rafa;

import java.util.Scanner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateB);
        final TextView RM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.returnMoney1);
        final EditText GM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gMoney);
        final EditText COP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cOP);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    int givedMoney = Integer.parseInt(GM.getText().toString());
                    // String returnMoney = RM.getText().toString();
                    // String CostOfProduct = COP.getText().toString();
                    int CostOfProduct = Integer.parseInt(COP.getText().toString());
                    String parts[] = COP.getText().toString().split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        CostOfProduct += Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
                    }
                    int returnmoney;
                    returnmoney = givedMoney - CostOfProduct;
                    if (givedMoney < CostOfProduct) {
                        returnmoney = CostOfProduct - givedMoney;
                        RM.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        RM.setText("Need more " + returnmoney + " den");
                        return;
                    }
                    RM.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    RM.setText(returnmoney + " den");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and now when ill run the application doesn't calculate good the numbers its confused

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you paste the LOG-CAT errors please..

Comment: No, i cant run the application cause maybe there is no method like .split(); "The method split(String) is undefined for the type Editable" this is giving

Comment: getText().toString().split(" ");

Comment: Thank you techiServices works, but why when i have tried that doesn't ? :D

Comment: String[] parts = COP.getText().split(" ");// ERROR is on this line !!! You missed the toString() on that line.

Comment: "and now when ill run the application doesn't calculate good the numbers its confused" - this is hardly a problem description that helps anyone help you. Please be more specific.

Comment: example: Ill put 100 in "Cost of Product" and in "Gived Money" 200 saying me "Need more 100" that's the error and btw need to show me just "100den" my English its not so good and cant explain better ... :/

Comment: i think its giving +10 or -10 i don't know its confusing :/

Comment: ok i have fix this problem but i have now another question how do i calculate the first numbers for example: 20 40 50 100 30 etc
Fixed Code: `int number2 = Integer.parseInt(GM.getText().toString());
     //int CostOfProduct = Integer.parseInt(COP.getText().toString());
     String[] parts = COP.getText().toString().split(" ");
     int number1 = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      number1 += Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
     }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the error is you are experiencing. Have you tried this:

```
COP.getText().toString().split("\\s+");
```

String.split() takes a regular expression as its first parameter. By using this regular expression you also handle the case where someone has multiple white space characters right after another.

Also I don't understand why you initialize CostOfProduct with Integer.parseInt(COP.getText().toString()); and then add to it using parts of the same TextView.

I would use this instead:

```
                int CostOfProduct = 0;
                String parts[] = COP.getText().toString().split("\\s+");
```

A better implementation also would account for getText() returning null or empty strings.

Comment: Good point, the code as it is now will either fail with a NumberFormatException on line 2, or cause `CostOfProduct` to be set to twice the integer value of `COP`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the exception statement, but I believe that the return type of `COP.getText()` is not `java.lang.String` (correct me if I'm wrong, I can't test it at this time). That should cause a compilation error, though. If that is the problem, then `COP.getText().toString().split(" ")` should work.